# Why my Lazy Loaded Angular LoginModule imports the same main.js as before( eager loading )

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Actually I'm changing the design of my app to make it Modular, Now I lazy loaded my first page ( /login ) which Actually lazy load the LoginModule when the app is refreshed or invoked,
There is a behaviour I didn't really get it: Comparing to the old eager process there is no difference between lazy loaded my LoginModule only or eager load it
I just inspect the network tab of an old eager Login page( another branch -Eager- ), the size of main.js loaded is the same as  My LoginModule get loaded lazily, they have the same size..
meaning that my LoginModule is loading everything at startup

Is that Normal ?Thx

[This is the screnshot of my Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPUwL.png)

Comment: please have a look https://chitaranjanbiswal93.medium.com/understanding-vendor-js-polyfill-js-style-css-main-js-and-runtime-js-in-an-angular-application-d060e4fce2fa#:~:text=of%20your%20application.-,The%20main.,for%20rendering%20in%20the%20browser.

Comment: It depends ... want is not possible is just flag a module to be lazy loaded. You need to check, if the module is really independent. As soon as the login module is still imported somewhere else it is compiled as before.